# Will Raspberry Pi with OwnCloud and RAID setup be fast enough?

Tags: networking, usb, hardware

I want to set up a raspberry Pi with OwnCloud on it and a set of external USB  drives (3.0). These drives will also be setup in a RAID. Will this setup be capable of high enough speeds to make this useable? Does anyone have experience with this?

I will also be setting up a separate Raspberry Pi with some VMs that will use the OwnCloud as their files backing. Will that be too slow?

Answer (score 2):

> Will this setup be capable of high enough speeds to make this useable?

I get about 30 MB/s either way to an external HDD.

> I will also be setting up a separate Raspberry Pi with some VMs

You choices there are I think limited; there are no real VMs available, but you may be able to use [containers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC).

Comment: 30 MB/s is [fairly decent for USB 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus#USB_2.0) (you'll never get the 480 MBit/s), but you probably meant to refer to USB 3.0 -- which the Pi doesn't support, so it won't be any faster with a 3.0-device than with a 2.0-device.

Comment: @n.st Actually I thought USB 2.0 was upto 150 **MB/s** -- but I'm wrong.  So it's not so bad.

Comment: @goldilocks What's the setup you have that gives 30MB/s? (and is that megabytes or megabits?)

Comment: @DonRhummy : MB = Megabytes.  That's with an external HDD attached to a powered hub.  Besides being waterproof, I don't think there's anything unusual about the HDD.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not. It does depend on your needs of course.

Remember that getting data to the network from a USB HDD has to fight over a single USB channel.

I see real speeds of about 10MB/s which is slooow if you are waiting for a large file to copy over.

For background tasks like backups etc. You can transfer a decent amount per hour/day

Answer (score 1):

I've been running ownCloud on an RPi B+ for a while, with the files residing on an external NAS. File upload/download speed was Ok -- you're limited to 10 MB/s in any case because of the Pi's 100 Mbit/s Ethernet interface. But, the CPU utilization was near 100% because of all the PHP and MySQL processing, leading to pretty bad response times when handling multiple files. I upgraded to an RPi 2 now, which seems more than fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the single most important performance trick for OwnCloud / NextCloud is to enable [HTTP2](https://http2.pro/). This will literally save you 2-5 seconds in every page load, starting with the login.

The next big step is to disable [transactional file locks](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/10.4/admin_manual/configuration/files/files_locking_transactional.html) if you don't need them (no files shared between users and no schizophrenic users opening multiple sessions and simultaneously editing the same file), or at least moving them to `memcache.locking` backend instead of the database.

Only once the above optimizations are done, the performance gain from a RAID storage may start to matter.